# #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql, errors

When I Import Mysql from local server to web ser it is showng me error

## 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' in Creating wordpress wp_comment table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_commentmeta` (
//
//
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
 #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

My mysql version is

```
Version information: 4.0.4, latest stable version: 4.4.10 (local version)

Version information: 4.0.10.7, latest stable version: 4.4.10( server version)
```

Please help me to solve out the error

Comment: Either update your server's (frankly ancient) MySQL to 5.5.3 (at least) or edit the import file, replacing all instances of `utf8mb4` with `utf8`.

Comment: How do you create your import file? If you use phpMyAdmin then replace compatibility mode `NONE` ( default ) with `MYSQL40`. No manual editing of the resulting file will be necessary. If you use a database backup plugin which does not support compatibilty modes then find the call to `mysqldump` command and add `--compatible=mysql40` parameter to it.

Comment: Of note, `utf8mb4` was introduced to fix security issues and introduce support for emoji

Answer (score 4):

WordPress does not support MySQL 4 :

> To run WordPress your host just needs a couple of things:
>
> MySQL version **5.0** or greater (recommended: MySQL **5.5** or greater)
>
> https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

While the utf8mb4 encoding is recent change and you might work around it, *overall* you still need compatible MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

From [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911733/error-1115-42000-unknown-character-set-utf8mb4-in-mysql)

Your version does not support that character set, I believe it was 5.5.3 that introduced it. You should upgrade your mysql to the version you used to export this file.

The error is then quite clear: you set a certain character set in your code, but your mysql version does not support it, and therefore does not know about it.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html :

> utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8

so maybe there is a chance you can just make it utf8, close your eyes and hope, but that would depend on your data, and I'd not recommend it.

Answer (score -3):

simply open your exported database in a text editor and replace all utf8mb4 with utf8 and export after.
just be critical to choose the right character set when exporting databases.